# How can I solve the following equation for k?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the following equation for k, where s1,s2,s3 are given constants:

```
      eq = s1/s2 - 
      Sqrt[2^(1/k) (1/s3)^(-1/k) (-k Gamma[1 + 1/k]^2 + Gamma[1/k])]/((2^(
      1/(2 k))) ((1/s3)^(-1/(2 k))) (Gamma[1 + 1/k]))
```

Comment: This is not an equation. Do you mean :   eq=  ... == 0?

Comment: `Assuming[k > 0 && s3 > 0, FullSimplify[eq]]` shows that your expression does not depend on $s_3$. Setting $f=s_1/s_2$ then gives a [numerical problem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) for $k(f)$ if $0\le f<\sqrt{\gamma}$; an analytic solution does not seem to exist.

Comment: Dear Daniel, yes =0

Comment: Dear Roman, many thanks for useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq = s1/s2 - 
   Sqrt[2^(1/k) (1/s3)^(-1/k) (-k Gamma[1 + 1/k]^2 + 
        Gamma[1/k])]/((2^(1/(2 k))) ((1/s3)^(-1/(2 k))) (Gamma[1 + 1/k]));
```

You will need to assign values to `{s1, s2, s3}` and solve numerically in a specified interval.

```
{s1, s2, s3} = {1, 2, 3};
```

In this instance the roots are at

```
sol = NSolve[{eq == 0, -3/2 < k < 5/2}, k, Reals, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {{k -> -0.411757197097451}, {k -> -0.355176064780969}, 
    {k -> 1.95552255578855}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eq /. sol

(* {0.*10^-14, 0.*10^-14, 0.*10^-15} *)
```

There are discontinuities at `k == 1/n` for `n` a negative integer.

```
Prepend[
  Flatten[
   Outer[{#1, #2, Limit[eq, k -> #1, Direction -> #2]} &,
    (-1/# & /@ Range[5]),
    {"FromBelow", "FromAbove"}], 1],
  {"k", "Direction", "Limit"}] //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Consequently, there is also a root in the limit as `k` approaches `-1/4` from above.

```
Plot[eq, {k, -3/2, 5/2},
 PlotRange -> {-1/4, 1/4},
 PlotStyle -> LightGray,
 PlotPoints -> 300,
 MaxRecursion -> 10,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 Epilog -> {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{k, eq} /. sol],
   Red, Point[{-1/4, 0}]},
 Exclusions -> (-1/# & /@ Range[3])]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Bob.